# Proper journal for a preprint in complex geometry

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I ran into the very cryptic paper [Proper analytic embedding of $\mathbb{C P}^1$ minus a Cantor set into $\mathbb C^2$](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Eorevkov/cantor.pdf) by Orekvov on proper holomorphic embedding of the complement of a Cantor set $C$ inside the Riemann Sphere $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$ into $\Bbb C^2$. The paper is extremely cryptical (≈ 1 page) so I wrote down all the details in [Di Salvo - Extended explanation of Orevkov's preprint on proper holomorphic embeddings of complements of Cantor sets in $\mathbb C^2$ and a discussion of their measure](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.05046) and I have moreover shown that it is natural for such a Cantor set $C$ to have 0 Hausdorff measure.

Is such a preprint worth publication? If so, what is a suitable journal?

Comment: I think it is probably as well not to post here a public disparagement of someone else's paper such as calling it "very cryptic[al]" (besides which I do not think shortness is evidence of a paper being cryptic).  It seems that it would probably work as well to say that you have written up a more detailed explication of the original work, without needing to make any public judgement on the work itself.

Comment: Thank You for Your comment. The preprint I linked is a part of my PhD thesis, and while doing it, two out of three professors in my group didn't manage to really understand it. I know that everything other than Math is subjective, but when we compare with the outside world we get a term of comparison. This is why I felt allowed to describe it as "cryptic". No means of judgment.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if not already peer-reviewed and then published in a journal, the manuscript that you are going to submit for peer-review is still called a preprint (even if it has already been uploaded on the arXiv).
Anyway, since it has been accepted by the arXiv moderators, in my opinion, it would be a good idea to try to submit it (I am not skilled enough in this field to perform any preliminary review of your manuscript, I can only say that adding a $100$ to $250$ words abstract at the the beginning could be nice).

Now, if I am not getting wrong, your topic should fall inside the MSC 2020 category 32HXX (e.g., 32H02 - Holomorphic mappings, (holomorphic) embeddings and related questions in several complex variables) or at least 32XX.
Thus, a very simple option to find a journal could be to perform a deep search on big databases as SJR $\rightarrow$ *Geometry and Topology* https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?category=2608, returning $99$ results (e.g., the *Journal of Geometric Analysis* that includes papers such as https://doi.org/10.1007/s12220-012-9306-4 could be a candidate) which could fit quite well (just my two cents).
Good luck.